# Returning a reference to a temporary

Tags: c++

I'm watching [this talk from cppcon17](https://youtu.be/lkgszkPnV8g?t=769) and am trying to replicate and understand the presented bugs.
However, I'm not able to replicate/understand bug #3 in the talk (timestamp is in the link above). I've written this minimal example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>


const std::string& getDefault(const std::map<int, std::string>& map, const int key, const std::string& defVal) {
    auto pos = map.find(key);
    return (pos != map.end() ? pos->second : defVal);
}

void printer(const std::string& str) {
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}

int main () {
    std::map<int, std::string> myMap { {1, "dog"}, {2, "cat"}};
    auto& retVal = getDefault(myMap, 3, "pizza");
    printer(retVal);
    return 0;
}
```

As I understand the problem, the temporary default value of "pizza" should not be returned by reference, because it should get deleted.
But why does this example work anyway? I was expecting an error due to a reference that is no longer valid.

*Edit*: I've modified the example slightly to highlight that the problem still occurs, if the temporary is on another line.

Comment: Welcome to undefined behavior land, where anything is possible.

Comment: The temporary is destroyed at the end of the line (;) where it is created. So isn't destroyed when processed in getdefault as you pass by reference. Change it to pass by value and you get issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code, i.e. `std::cout << getDefault(myMap, 3, "pizza") << std::endl;` is valid; the [temporary](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime) will be destroyed after the full expression, i.e. after the `;`, the returned reference remains valid when being passed to and printed out by `operator<<` of `std::cout`.

> All temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression that (lexically) contains the point where they were created,

**EDIT**

Your updated code has undefined behavior. After the `;` the temporary object has been destroyed and `retVal` is dangled; any dereference on it leads to UB.

Comment: That's what I've thought at first, but I've also rewritten the example to put the print statement in a seperate function on another line. The behavior is the same.

Comment: @Picard hmm, that would really depend on your implementation. We cannot judge that without the code.

Comment: @Picard Now you got UB, means anything is possible.

Comment: thanks! I think I understand the problem now. So the value I get may or may not be correct, the memory address might get overwritten. It was probably just "luck" that the correct value was still there.

Comment: @Picard Yes. But I think it's unluck. :) It seems working but it's just fake.